# My personal blog deployed on Github cannot be updated

Tags: git, github, blogs, hexo

I've been trying to build a personal blog recently. My strategy is to use **hexo** and deploy it on **GitHub**.

I have this problem:

When I write a new blog on my local computer and try to update it on my personal page, I use **git bash** to push it to the remote repository, and then call the **“hexo server”**[(Photos: my git bash)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZG5e.png)  command to open **localhost:4000** to see if the blog is updated. **My computer shows that the blog page has been updated locally**.[Photos: page on my localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHsOP.png)

But when I open **“username.github.io”**， it doesn't update.[Photos: page on username.github.io](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfncm.png)

I really need your help.Thank you!

Comment: So you've follow the instructions in https://hexo.io/docs/github-pages ? Looking at https://github.com/Sieoer/sieoer.github.io/tree/main/.github it seems that you have not done that.

Comment: I follow the instructions in https://hexo.io/docs/one-command-deployment. I install hexo-deployer-git, and run commands "hexo clean" and "hexo deploy".

Comment: What does your `_config.yml` look like? [Edit] your question to include this. It seems your repo doesn't have a `gh-pages` branch which should be present if you followed the instructions correctly.